# Referencing multiple cells VBA Autofilter

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to apply an autofilter to a range and filter on one of the columns by looking for the same value that is contained in several reference cells:

```
Sub filter()

Range("B6:N9000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array(Range("C2").Value, Range("D2").Value, Range("E2").Value )

End Sub
```

The problem however is the filter only applies the LAST cell referenced in the code, ie for above it ONLY looks up "E2", not "C2" & "D2" & "E2"

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Are you filtering for values that match at least one of C,D,E2 or for values that must fulfill all three?

Comment: Hi @Verzweifler I'm searching for values that match at least 1 of C2, D2, E2

Comment: Please try adding `Operator:=xlFilterValues` to your call and see if that works!

Comment: Thank you for that @Verzweifler . I'm fairly new to VBA unfortunately, so could you suggest where in the code to add this? Thanks

Comment: @JS142 - I googled `Operator:=xlFilterValues` and had an answer in less time than it took to type this sentence.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comment @Jeeped . Have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put an answer under this: You want to add the argument `Operator:=xlFilterValues` to your call, so it will look like this:

```
Range("B6:N9000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Array(Range("C2").Value, _
    Range("D2").Value, Range("E2").Value), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

or

```
[B6:N9000].AutoFilter Field:=2, _
    Criteria1:=Array([C2].Value, [D2].Value, [E2].Value), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Comment: @Vasily Although [B6:N9000] is a nice (and shorter) way to reference ranges, I didn't want to confuse someone who's "fairly new to VBA" with the [Evaluate Command](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52372) ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. Unfortunately I'm getting a "Compile error: Expected: end of statement" and it is highlighting 'Operator' in my code

Comment: Oh darn - we've forgotten a comma before `Operator:=xlFilterValues`, see the edited post. Please try again :-)

Comment: Perfection! Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @JS142 if this answer solved your problem you need to accept it,  users with similar issue will see that this is solution